# How to construct this function continuously?

Tags: functions, simplex

I am looking for a continuous function $f$ mapping each point $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ on the standard triangle <sub>(this means $\sum_{i}x_i=1$ and $\forall i: x_i\geq 0$)</sub> to another point $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ on the standard triangle, with the following property.

If, for some $i$, $x_i=0$, then:

- $y_i$ is a maximum element in $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$;
- For some $j\neq i$, $y_j=0$.

I could find the value of $f$ in some special points. For example, on the face $x_3=0$:

- $f(1,0,0) = (0,1/2,1/2)$ [since both $y_2$ and $y_3$ must be maximum, and $y_1$ must be zero].
- $f(1/2,1/2,0) = (0,0,1)$; [since $y_3$ must be maximum, and some of $y_1,y_2$ must be zero].
- $f(0,1,0) = (1/2,0,1/2)$.

The function on the boundary can be intrapolated between these points, e.g.:

- $f(3/4,1/4,0) = (0,1/4,3/4)$;
- $f(1/4,3/4,0) = (1/4,0,3/4)$;

But how can I extend this to a continuous function on the entire standard simplex?

Comment: This may sound naive but I can't figure how you get  $f(1/4,3/4,0) = (1/4,0,3/4)$ from your statements. What prevent $f(1/4,3/4,0) to be equal to (0,0,1)$ or  $(1/10,0,9/10)$ for instance?

Comment: @Jeanba this is an arbitrary intrapolation between $(0,1/2,1/2)$ and $(0,0,1)$. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: I think now I visualize somehow the transformation but it's not so easy to characterize it. If I'm seeing it correctly It's a mixed of a rotation of angle Pi of the triangle and a multiplication by 1/2 or 2 of the distance of the point with respect of the center of rotation depending on the position of this point with respect to the tangent. The center of the transformation being the point (1/3,1/3,1/3).